# How add channel for wolframclient using conda?

Tags: python

I want to use the wolframclient Python package in Mathematica. The docs suggest using `pip install wolframclient`.

However, my main Python installation is within conda, so I do *not* want to use `pip`, but instead a standard `conda install wolframclient`. (The problem with using `pip` is that the added package's dependencies may interfere with what conda has already installed and knows about.)

The `wolframclient` package is at https://pypi.org/project/wolframclient/. But by default conda does not know about pypi.org. I tried the command `conda config --add channels pipy`, but `conda install wolframclient` says the channel is "not accessible or is invalid".

I think the problem is that the files at `https://pypi.org/project/wolframclient/` are not already in the form of a conda package.

How might one proceed?

Comment: Slightly sub-optimal workaround: the dependencies are listed in `setup.py`; you can install them beforehand via the usual conda channels. This way you are sure that `pip install wolframclient` will not pollute your environment.

Comment: Then which download do I want, to see `setup.py`: `wolframclient-1.1.2.tar.gz` or `wolframclient-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`?

Comment: I simply cloned the github repo.